# I keep getting a bottom overflowed by 128 pixels for my flutter app even when tried wrapping some widgets in an Expanded

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I keep getting an error which says a part of my app overflowed by certain pixels, as i was developing it on my phone it looked fine, but as i installed it on other devices i keep getting errors, i tried wrapping some of my widgets in an Expanded but im still getting the error

this is how it looked on my phone, it looked great

[How the app looked on my device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcqHA.jpg)

[How the app looked after i installed on a different device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jcctt.jpg)

Here is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hotel_search/FadeAnimation.dart';
import 'package:hotel_search/home_page.dart';


import 'package:page_transition/page_transition.dart';

class StarterPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StarterPageState createState() => _StarterPageState();
}

class _StarterPageState extends State<StarterPage> with TickerProviderStateMixin{
  AnimationController _animationController;
  Animation<double> _animation;

  bool _textVisible = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100)
    );

    _animation = Tween<double>(
      begin: 1.0,
      end: 25.0
    ).animate(_animationController);

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  void _onTap() {
    setState(() {
      _textVisible = false;
    });

    _animationController.forward().then((f) => 
      Navigator.push(context, PageTransition(type: PageTransitionType.fade, child: HomePage()))
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/images/back.jpg'), 
            fit: BoxFit.cover
          )
        ),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              colors: [
                Colors.black.withOpacity(.9),
                Colors.black.withOpacity(.8),
                Colors.black.withOpacity(.2),
              ]
            )
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[

               Expanded(

           child:Container( 
             child: Column(
              
              children: <Widget>[
                Container( width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,height: 400, 
                child:FadeAnimation(.5, Image.asset(
              "assets/images/brand.png", 
              width: 0,
              height:0,  
              fit: BoxFit.contain,)),),
                SizedBox(height: 30,),
                
                Container( width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child:FadeAnimation(.5, Text('Welcome', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 50, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)),), 
                SizedBox(height: 20,),

                
                Container( width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: FadeAnimation(1, Text("Sunbird Hotels and Resorts is Malawi’s leading hotel chain", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, height: 1.4, fontSize: 18),)),),
                SizedBox(height: 0,) 
                
                
              ]
             )
           ))   
           
                        
                ,Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                
                  
                FadeAnimation(1.2, 
                
                ScaleTransition(
                  scale: _animation,
                  child: Container( 

                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2.3,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      
                      color: Colors.white
                    ),
                    child: AnimatedOpacity(
                      opacity: _textVisible ? 1.0 : 0.0,
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 50),
                      child: MaterialButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => HomePage()));
                              

                        },
                        minWidth: double.infinity,
                        child: Text("JOIN", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20,fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),),
                      ),
                    )
                  )),
                ),


                SizedBox(width: 10,),

                 FadeAnimation(1.2, 
                
                ScaleTransition(
                  scale: _animation,
                  child: Container(

                     width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2.3,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      
                      color: Color(0xff008d4b)
                    ),
                    child: AnimatedOpacity(
                      opacity: _textVisible ? 1.0 : 0.0,
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 50),
                      child: MaterialButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => HomePage()));
                              

                        },
                        minWidth: double.infinity,
                        child: Text("SIGN IN", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20,fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),),
                      ),
                    )
                  )),
                )
                
                
                
                
                
                
                
                
                
                
                
                
                
                
                
                
                
                
                ]),










                SizedBox(height: 30,),
                FadeAnimation(1.4,
                AnimatedOpacity(
                  opacity: _textVisible ? 1.0 : 0.0,
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 50),
                  child: Align(
                    child: Text("Continue as a Guest", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70, fontSize: 15),),
                  ),
                )),
                SizedBox(height: 30,),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi interesting not sure if adding margin might work

Answer (score 0):

Make the body of your Scaffold a SingleChildScrollView and the first container it's child.